# Why shared_ptr and weak_ptr working like this? (for resolve circular ref)

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, weak-ptr

I want know about shared_ptr. After study, I know that the weak_ptr can resolve the circular reference problem in shared_ptr and, I write some code for testing it.

**Code**

```
class B;

class A
{
public:
    std::shared_ptr<B> _b;
    ~A() 
    {
        std::cout << "A dtor: " << _b.use_count() << std::endl; 
    }
};

class B
{
public:
    std::weak_ptr<A> _a;
    ~B() { std::cout << "B dtor: " << _a.use_count() << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    {
        std::shared_ptr<A> a(new A);
        std::shared_ptr<B> b(new B);

        std::cout << "a ref count: " << a.use_count() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "b ref count: " << b.use_count() << std::endl;

        a->_b = b;
        b->_a = a;

        std::cout << "a ref count: " << a.use_count() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "b ref count: " << b.use_count() << std::endl;
    }

    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
a ref count: 1
b ref count: 1
a ref count: 1
b ref count: 2
A dtor: 1
B dtor: 0
```

I don't know why this code working like this. I think "A dtor: 2" and "B dtor: 0" will be corrent result. Please give me answer for it.

Comment: Use `std::make_shared` instead of `a(new A)` - It makes good programming practice

Answer (score 4):

`b` is destructed before `a` (since destruction here occurs in the opposite order of construction) which reduces it's `use_count` by 1.

- Construct a - a use_count = 1
- Construct b - b use_count = 1
- Assign b to A::b_ member - b use_count = 2
- Assign a to B::a_ member - a use_count = 1
- Destruct b - b use_count = 1
- Destruct a which prints 1 as b's use_count

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think that far. I thought destruct operation always call dtor. but only reduce reference count happen. Thank you.

Comment: @GaeJem Destructing an object will always call it's destructor. In this case when `b` destructs it calls `~std::shared_ptr<B>()' which reduces the use_count of the resource it owns by 1. When the use_count reaches 0 then `~std::shared_ptr<B>()' will delete the resource it owns which in this case will involve calling `~B()`.